# Visualize first responder?

Tags: cocoa, appkit, first-responder, nsresponder

Is there some kind of AppKit/`NSDocument`/`NSApplication` debugging option, debugging flag or other third-party extension to visualize the current `firstResponder` for any given `NSWindow` instance in the current application?

We're building a single-window application that's dynamically loading and swapping views in and out of the window and keeping track/debugging the current `firstResponder` is becoming a pain in the neck..

Any hints/practices much appreciated!